# Add dynamic content to single activity in android studio / java

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dynamic-programming

I am trying to learn android studio and java more specifically, I am used to using html / php so forgive me for my lack of knowledge here..

Lets say I am making a golf app for this example, in html / php and I have a database with the following columns-

```
Course | Hole | Yardage
```

I also have a php file called getInfo.php

This variable is being passed from lets say index.php which has a list of buttons for each course in our app and is located in getInfo.php.

```
 $course = $_GET['course'];
```

So I can pass that variable in a URL to retrieve its value for use in getInfo.php and pull the data from the database based on the course the user chose..

My question is whats the equivalent in AS / Java? Can I set the course info in a xml file and retrieve it dynamically to a single activity so I don't have to create a new activity for each hole for each course as there potentially could be thousands of courses.. Just looking for the best approach to start learning..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `RecyclerView` to show all the list of holes in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, to parse all the information you need to use a `RecyclerViewAdapter` and the information you can retrieve it from a DB, an String array or from an API, it deppends on you

Comment: Thanks! I will research RecyclerView